# Is there any script like Greasemonkey that enables to read/write files?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

Greasemonkey is a great addon but its main drawback is that its not possible to read/write files from hard disk. So, is there any other addon that can read/write files from hard disk??

Comment: Not sure what you mean here; all addons can read/write files, but Greasemonkey doesn't expose that ability to its scripts, only [GM_setValue][1] etc.

  [1]: http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/index.php) might well work for you**, and it does do file IO.

---

Or if you feel particularly frisky, you could fork off of [the Greasemonkey code](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey) and make a version that bypasses the file restrictions.

Comment: If someone is still interested on 2019. The linked pafe has only Chickenfoot 1.0.7. However, there is a later v1.0.9 (never accepted by Mozilla/AMO) which can work in quite recent  Firefox (XUL/preQuantum), Waterfox or Basilisk browser.