# Storing or loggin data with greasemonkey which can be processed later

Tags: javascript, json, excel, greasemonkey, storing-data

I'm curently busy on a site for which i want to write a greasemonkey script that logs all the data, or at least certain postions of it, and saves in an file that will be interperatable fo ms excell. Is that possible? say for example i take this snippet of data:

```
 {"d":[["","","y","ZAR","1","49517","6458, 8270, 8270, 8270, 7635",null,"1.40","6458","0:13:30","","12","","C","30",null],["y","-00:00","y","ZAR","2","49593","6458, 6458, 6458, 6458, 6458",null,"2.92","6458","0:13:37","","12","","L","12","Ve4mYdrvkkQMKxBH1\/1VMtDTCDQBRspg5jB8jjY08zg="],["","","y","ZAR","3","49058","7456, 9216, 6458, 5153, 7456",null,"194.40","7456","0:00:31","","1100","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","4","49597","2935, 6554",null,"1.22","2935","0:01:16","","12","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","5","49590","4440, 0518, 5343, 2625, 4848",null,"0.95","4440","0:15:58","","5","","L",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","6","49591","4848, 4440, 4440, 0518, 2625",null,"1.81","4848","0:16:05","","12","","L",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","7","49595","6458",null,"5.55","6458","0:04:13","","55","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","8","49596","",null,"2.90","NONE","0:04:35","","29","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","9","49496","6458, 2427, 2427, 7863, 5845",null,"2.56","6458","0:06:07","","10","","B",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","10","49524","6458, 2427, 7863, 7863, 5845",null,"1.67","6458","0:06:00","","5","","B",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","11","49539","6458, 2427, 7863, 7863, 0764",null,"2.02","6458","0:04:25","","10","","B",null,null]]}
```

, Read it into an 2d array, which Brock Adams helped me with.

```
var myJson              = '{"d":[["","","y","ZAR","1","49517","6458, 8270, 8270, 8270, 7635",null,"1.40","6458","0:13:30","","12","","C","30",null],["y","-00:00","y","ZAR","2","49593","6458, 6458, 6458, 6458, 6458",null,"2.92","6458","0:13:37","","12","","L","12","Ve4mYdrvkkQMKxBH1\/1VMtDTCDQBRspg5jB8jjY08zg="],["","","y","ZAR","3","49058","7456, 9216, 6458, 5153, 7456",null,"194.40","7456","0:00:31","","1100","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","4","49597","2935, 6554",null,"1.22","2935","0:01:16","","12","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","5","49590","4440, 0518, 5343, 2625, 4848",null,"0.95","4440","0:15:58","","5","","L",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","6","49591","4848, 4440, 4440, 0518, 2625",null,"1.81","4848","0:16:05","","12","","L",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","7","49595","6458",null,"5.55","6458","0:04:13","","55","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","8","49596","",null,"2.90","NONE","0:04:35","","29","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","9","49496","6458, 2427, 2427, 7863, 5845",null,"2.56","6458","0:06:07","","10","","B",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","10","49524","6458, 2427, 7863, 7863, 5845",null,"1.67","6458","0:06:00","","5","","B",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","11","49539","6458, 2427, 7863, 7863, 0764",null,"2.02","6458","0:04:25","","10","","B",null,null]]}'
var jsonObj             = $.parseJSON (myJson);

//--- The JSON should return a 2-D array, named "d".
var arrayOfAuctions     = jsonObj.d;

//--- Loop over each row in the array.
$.each (
    arrayOfAuctions,
    function (rowIndex, singleAuctionData) {

        //--- Print the 7th column.
        console.log ('Row: ' + (parseInt (rowIndex) + 1) + ' Column: 7  Value: ' + singleAuctionData[6]);
    }
);
```

now i want to write this data of the array over into an file which i can later go and open in excell and go over it. By using GM_setValue, can it be done? How would the easiest way be to go on with it?

Thanks.

Comment: Saving to a CSV file to open in Excel would be the easiest way, but I don't think you can save files in GreaseMonkey: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979347/is-there-any-script-like-greasemonkey-that-enables-to-read-write-files

Comment: I think the easiest way to go will be by storing on a remote server... just still a bit unsure of how to go ahead with it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greasemonkey cannot write to a file, and using `GM_setValue` or local storage would be a pain to get into a file.  You do not want to store very many values using `GM_setValue` anyway, since these are stored in the browser preferences.

You mentioned a remote server.
Yes, GM can send the data to a remote server (or even your local machine if it is running something like XAMPP).  With a little more work, you could also send the data to Google docs, or similar.

It's not clear what data you want to send (assuming you don't just send the entire `arrayOfAuctions`).

So, say, you've analyzed the data and determined that you want these columns:

```
Column 
Index       Meaning / Purpose
------      --------------------------------
   4        Auction display number
   5        Auction ID
   8        Current Price
   9        High bidder ID
  10        Time Remaining
  12        Up to???
```

Then you could isolate the data of interest like so:

```
//--- Start custom, 2-D array.
var myAuctionData       = [ [ 'DisplayNumber', 'AuctionID', 'CurrentPrice',
                            'HighbidderID', 'TimeRemaining', 'Upto'
                        ] ];

//--- Loop over each row in the array, storing desired data.
$.each (
    arrayOfAuctions,
    function (rowIndex, singleAuctionData)
    {
        myAuctionData.push ( [
            singleAuctionData[4], singleAuctionData[5],  singleAuctionData[8],
            singleAuctionData[9], singleAuctionData[10], singleAuctionData[12]
        ] );
    }
);
```

And send it to your server like so:

```
SerializedAuctionData  = JSON.stringify (myAuctionData);

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     "POST",
    url:        "http://localhost/YourDir/LogAuctionData.php",
    data:       SerializedAuctionData,
    headers:    {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
} );
```

The server can be using whatever technology you are comfortable with.
If it was a PHP page, it could extract the JSON data like so:

```
$AuctionData = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
print_r ($AuctionData);
```

The server page *could* write a csv or xls file, but since lots of data will be posted, once per second, it would probably be smarter to use a mySQL database.

Comment: Quote"So, say, you've analyzed the data and determined that you want these columns:

Column 
Index       Meaning / Purpose
------      ----------------------------
   4        Auction display number
   5        Auction ID
   8        Current Price
   9        High bidder ID
  10        Time Remaining
  12        Up to???"
 . yes , that is about what i had in mind...:) but mine would hav been stored less times, not every second. the info i would hav been intersted in is: auction display number. starting bid, closing bid. It would cut down a lot on the data, as it wont be saving it every second.

Comment: You mentioned i can store it on my own machine...but i need XAMPP). can u pls elaborate what it is and how i install/implement it on my machine? How does it work? first time i came accross it..:)

Comment: @ Brock, then if i'm not storing the data every second, but only when an auction is closed, i would only do: `$AuctionData = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
print_r ($AuctionData);'
if auction closed is true... right? not every second.

Comment: @ Brock. ok thanks, found XAMPP. i also got Win7 64-bit. found this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170747 ,so will try it.

Comment: @Ludwig, you don't need XAMPP, you need any server technology like Coldfusion, PHP, Python, Java, .net, etc.  XAMPP is just a fast way to get a popular free server (PHP) up and running.  If you've never written web apps before, You've got a bit of a learning curve ahead. ... ... Note that that starter PHP code will do nothing visible if you are not familiar with PHP debugging. ... ... Yes, you and your script are completely in charge of how often `GM_xmlhttpRequest` gets called. (It doesn't have to be once per second.)

Comment: this is getting compicated...:O so the gm script wont create an usable php by its own. I mut basically create one and pe-format it. From Php i know even less than gm. If i take tht starter php that has been saved by gm, and open it in a text editor, wont i be able to make out the basics that hav been saved, like with the array?

Comment: @brock, if i use something like appgini @ http://www.free-php.net/detail/link-759.html to create the php app i need, will it work?

Comment: @Ludwig, No GM can't create the PHP app.  You need a programmer for that.  AppGini will work, but is probably overkill for now.   If you don't know any web-app technologies, perhaps exploring how to use the Google-docs API might be faster (but still a bit of a challenge).  Unfortunately, what you want to do is not a trivial task.

Comment: Thanks! It really helps me figuring this out! ;)